# Spring controller method argument post init callback

Tags: spring, jackson

I have a controller method that takes a bean as an argument. This controller method accepts POST requests and the corresponding post body is populated inside the argument bean. I want to call the postInit method inside `PasswordChange` Object after this bean is initialized and the json has been deserialized but before the service call inside the controller method is made.I know there is the Spring's `@PostConstruct` but because I am using `Jackson` for json deserialization via the `MappingJacksonJsonView` I wasn't sure certain if this method would be reliably called. Can anybody tell me if this is infact a valid use of `@PostConstruct`.

I am using `Spring 3.2.8` with `Jackson-databind 2.3.2`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/passwordChange", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody PasswordInfo passwordInfo(@RequestBody @Valid PasswordChange passwordChange)
            throws PasswordChangeException {
        return passwordService.changePassword(passwordChange.getLoginKey(), passwordChange.getOldPassword(), passwordChange.getNewPassword());
    }
```

PasswordChange Bean.

```
 public class PasswordChange {


    private String loginKey;

    private String oldPassword;

    private String newPassword;

    @Autowired
    private LoginDao loginDao;

    private LoginEntity login;
    private Person person;


    public PasswordChange() {       
    }

    public PasswordChange(String loginKey, String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
        this.loginKey = loginKey;
        this.oldPassword = oldPassword;
        this.newPassword = newPassword;    
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postInit() {
            login = loginDao.findByLogin(loginKey);
        person = login.getCorePerson();
    }

}
```

Comment: Normally yes, `@PostConstruct` annotated method would be called in a Spring managed bean after Spring injects the dependencies (e.g. the `@Autowired loginDao`). But from what I can see here `PasswordChange` is not a Spring managed bean and not only `postInit()` won't be called but `loginDao` won't be injected either and will be null (unless you're using domain model injection technique with `@Configurable`...)

Comment: I am using `Java Config`, the PasswordChange's package is included in `@ComponentScan` basePackages. So, I know `loginDao` is being injected. So, I am guessing based on what you said @PostConstruct would be called. Can you post your comment as answer, I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Can't see any spring annotation on `PasswordChange` class so it's not really spring managed and definitely doesn't have `loginDao` injected.

Comment: BTW It's a bit of an anti-pattern in spring to mix business logic and data in one class. Are you sure you don't want that `loginDao` wired to your password service?

Comment: I need the `login` and `person` entities for Validation for which I am using JSR-303 constraints with Hibernate-Validator. So currently I am injecting loginDao into the `ConstraintValidator<A, V>` implementations. Somebody took a look at it and suggested against injecting `loginDao` into the constraints. What are your thoughts on inject loginDao into the constraints as opposed to the `bean`. On the other hand is it alright for a constraint to call the service classes to get the entities ? FYI, you don't see the constraint annotations on  `PasswordChange` class as I removed them before posting.

Comment: Turns out what was called an Anti-Pattern is what people are suggesting one should do. For example the link below lists the problem with Anemic domain models and DomainDrivenDesign. 
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/the-biggest-flaw-of-spring-web-applications/